# react js props in class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am facing one problem with one simple code.

i am having a props in my component tags called name and age. And i want to use this inside my class Login

my code look like this way

```
export default class App extends Component {

//constructor(props){

//super(props); //}

render(){ return(

  <div className="person">
  <h1>{  }</h1>
  <p> Your age is 37</p>


  </div>

); } }

ReactDOM.render(<App name="john" age="37"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i want to access the attribute of my component name and age. And render them in the above html.

Comment: How is the component receiving name and age? This looks like the root level component for React, so you aren't passing it any data at all, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data to the App, but not actually using it in the JSX.

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() { 
    const {name, age} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
        <p> Your age is {age}</p>
      </div>

    ); 
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App name="john" age="37"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: i also using this

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


but in your code i am thinking this line having a syntax error const {name, age} = this.props;

i also tested and it having a syntax error

Comment: i am using this {this.props.name} this works and correct syntax